# Error with Object in C# serlializing XSD

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd

I am trying to read an XML file into an object in a C# project. Basing it off this [article DON’T PARSE THAT XML!](http://elegantcode.com/2010/08/07/dont-parse-that-xml/) and this solution

> Then type
>
> xsd myFile.xsd /c
>
> This will generate a set of classes that you can add to your project,
>   and then you can deserialize an xml file with this simple code:
>
> 1: XmlSerializer serializer =     2: new
>   XmlSerializer(typeof(MyFile));    3:      4: Stream reader = new
>   FileStream("myFile.xml",FileMode.Open);    5:      6: MyFile myFile =
>   (MyFile) serializer.Deserialize(reader);   It really is that simple. 
>   There is no excuse for hand writing XML parsing code when you can
>   literally take an XML file you have never seen before and turn it into
>   an object in memory in 10 minutes. The serialization framework and XSD
>   tool provide options for using attributes to control how the XML is
>   generated also.

So I had already created my XSD and `xsd myFile.xsd /c` ran succeffuly.

In writing my code to serialize to object I keep getting XmlSerializer does not take a constructor with one argument.

When referring to the [MSDN Class docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [MSDN Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx) my code looks like it should work, what is wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer;

namespace testxmlc
{
    public class XmlSerializer
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main (string filename)
            {
                XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyFile));
                Stream reader = new FileStream("myFile.xml", FileMode.Open);
                MyFile myFile = (MyFile)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a class XmlSerializer that is conflicting with the .NET class XmlSerializer:

```
public class XmlSerializer
{
    class Program
    {
```

Also your usings are wrong.  You need "using System.IO", and "using System.Xml.Serialization", and get rid of "using System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer".

Comment: its close but it errors that MyFile is missing a directive or assembly reference.